# bigquery invalid character in create function

Tags: google-bigquery

My project id contains "-" character
So when I try to create a function like the following the error sayign I cannot use "-" is thrown

```
CREATE FUNCTION name-name
```

How cna I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the following syntax, it should work (backtick characters around the project and function name) :

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION `your-project.dataset.AddFourDivide`(x INT64, y INT64)
RETURNS FLOAT64
AS (
  (x + 4) / y
);
```